# How to draw line chart using pandas or matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a table like below:

```
date  category  num
xxx      a       10
xxx      b       23
xxx      c       11
..........
```

I want to draw a line chart that: 1. x axis is the time series, 2. y is the num, and 3. each category gets their own line, so in the above case there should be 3 lines.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the documentation for `matplotlib`, done a simple google search, anything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use seaborn lineplot.

```
sns.lineplot(x='date',y='num, data=df, hue='category',palette='bright)
```

Using hue should give you 3 separate graph.

You can also use matplotlib.
Here is the documentation for that:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html